# Link doesn't trigger any jquery action through Cucumber, Capybara

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

The thing is that I have some html page with a little of jquery that when I press the link "Add new booking number" it triggers some Jquery code that appends a new input text to the view, when I test it through the web browser it works, but I have this steps in a cucumber feature:

```
1. And I fill in "Booking" with "2FD5623A6"
2. And I follow "Add new booking number"
3. And show me the page
4. And I fill in "Booking 2" with "HGJD8FDU7"
```

the step 4. fails because the booking 2 label isn't generated when clicking the "Add new booking number" link, but with the step 3, when I manually click that link, the new field is correctly generated, so I don't know what's happening

I just solved a problem with capybara and cucumber-rails, I commented the following line

```
# require 'cucumber/rails/capybara_javascript_emulation' # Lets you click links with onclick javascript handlers without using @culerity or @javascript
```

because of this issue https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/issue/110

My gem versions are:

```
Using capybara (0.4.1)  Using
cucumber (0.10.0)  Using
cucumber-rails (0.3.2)
```

Can anyone can help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag your scenario with `@javascript` if you haven't done so yet.

```
@javascript
Scenario: do something AJAXy
  When I click the AJAX link
  …
```

Comment: Right, by default Cucumber and Capybara are not using a driver that can handle Javascript. (I think it uses Rack::Test by default?) When you tag it @javascript, you'll be using Selenium by default.